# Parsing using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to extract  content which comes after text Final Text: (not a tag) using Beautifulsoup.

i.e. expecting only

> `<td>0&nbsp;/&nbsp;22&nbsp;FAIL</td></tr><tr>`

Problem here is many tags doesn't have class or id etc. If i exctract only `<td>,` i will get all which is not required.

```
<td><strong>Final Text:</strong></td>
<td>0&nbsp;/&nbsp;22&nbsp;FAIL</td></tr><tr>
<td><strong>Ext:</strong></td>
<td>343&nbsp;/&nbsp;378&nbsp;FAIL</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `<strong>Final Text:</strong>` tag using `find('strong', text='Final Text:')`. Then, you can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method to get the next `<td>` tag.

```
html = '''
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Final Text:</strong></td>
        <td>0&nbsp;/&nbsp;22&nbsp;FAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Ext:</strong></td>
        <td>343&nbsp;/&nbsp;378&nbsp;FAIL</td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

txt = soup.find('strong', text='Final Text:').find_next('td')
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
<td>0 / 22 FAIL</td>
```

Comment: Simple & accurate. This is what i expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the content which you're trying to get always comes after the first index of the `<td></td>` tag. Why not get the second index of the list of elements?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

td_list = soup.find('td')
td_list[1]  # This would be the FAIL element
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, consider this HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Final Text:</strong></td>
        <td>0&nbsp;/&nbsp;22&nbsp;FAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Ext:</strong></td>
        <td>343&nbsp;/&nbsp;378&nbsp;FAIL</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This xpath will work

```
//*[contains(text(),'Final Text')]/parent::td/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr
```

Find tag containing text `Final Text`, get its parent `td`, then get its parent `tr` then get its following sibling `tr`